# BIND recursive query logging

Tags: bind

I have a BIND name server that has been purposefully enabled for recursion. However, I would like to log all the recursive queries that it handles/forwards.

I am using the following configuration:

```
logging
{
    channel default_debug {
        file "/var/log/named.log";
        severity dynamic;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-category yes;
    };
};
```

Recursive queries are not been written into `/var/log/named.log`. How can I log recursive queries?

Versions: ***BIND 9.8.2*** on ***CentOS 6.8***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
category queries { default_debug; };
```

Recursive queries are now been logged:

```
01-Jul-2016 20:28:29.758 queries: info: client 1.1.1.1#24009: query: bing.com IN MX + (2.2.2.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled query logging?

As logging every single query is generally seen as undesirable for normal operations it has to be enabled in one of these ways:

- Specifying the [`queries`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#the_category_phrase) category in the `logging` configuration section.
- Enabling [`querylog`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#boolean_options) in the `options` configuration section.
- Turning on [`querylog`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/man.rndc.html#id2662920) via `rndc` at runtime.

As a sidenote the specified path looks problematic. If you want to have `named` write to a file directly instead of logging via syslog (the default behavior), it's probably better to have a sub-directory dedicated to this (eg `/var/log/named/` or similar) as you can then set sensible permissions on that directory.

Comment: The path is absolutely fine. BIND is running in a chroot environment and I can see log entries. That is not the issue. I have enabled query logging however, like I mentioned, ***recursive*** queries are not been logged. Authoritative queries are logged.

Comment: @BruceBlacklaws Ok, so no queries logged with `+` in the last field?